# how to check every 3 x 3 box in sudoku?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sudoku

I am trying to build a sudoku solver without much googling around. Right now, I am working on a function to test whether the board is valid, which I will use later in a loop. This is what the function currently looks like.

```
def valid(board):

    s = 0

    for row in board:
        if row.count('1') == 1 and row.count('2') == 1 and row.count('3') == 1 and row.count('4') == 1 and row.count('5') == 1 and row.count('6') == 1 and row.count('7') == 1 and row.count('8') == 1 and row.count('9') == 1:
            s += 1

    for column in range(len(board)):
        if i[column].count('1') == 1 and i[column].count('2') == 1 and i[column].count('3') == 1 and i[column].count('4') == 1 and i[column].count('5') == 1 and i[column].count('6') == 1 and i[column].count('7') == 1 and i[column].count('8') == 1 and i[column].count('9') == 1:
            s += 1

    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')

    if s == 18:
        print('valid')
    else:
        print('no')
```

The valid board I am using to test is this array of arrays:

```
example = [['4','3','5','2','6','9','7','8','1'],['6','8','2','5','7','1','4','9','3'],['1','9','7','8','3','4','5','6','2'],

['8','2','6','1','9','5','3','4','7'],['3','7','4','6','8','2','9','1','5'],['9','5','1','7','4','3','6','2','8'],

['5','1','9','3','2','6','8','7','4'],['2','4','8','9','5','7','1','3','6'], ['7','6','3','4','1','8','2','5','9']]
```

I am certain this is not the most efficient way to go about this but I am really just trying to understand the problem. So, when a row has each number 1-9 appear once, I add 1 to my s variable. When each column meets the same criteria, I also add 1 to my s variable. So when each row and column has numbers 1-9 appear once in them, my s variable should be 18, but this does not make the board valid as I still have to check each 3x3 box meets their own criteria. In the end, the s variable should be equal to 27 for the board to be valid.

The code I have tried to make the 3x3 boxes print will only print the first 3x3 box, how can I make it repeat for each 3x3 box? Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks for the help.

Edit: I guess the brute force method would look like this:

```
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(3,6):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(3):
        for c in range(6,9):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')

    print('\n')
    print('\n')
    
    for r in range(3,6):
        for c in range(3):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(3,6):
        for c in range(3,6):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(3,6):
        for c in range(6,9):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')

    print('\n')
    for r in range(6,9):
        for c in range(3):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(6,9):
        for c in range(3,6):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
    for r in range(6,9):
        for c in range(6,9):
            print(board[r][c], end = '')
    print('\n')
```

edit 2, I found a better way to do this:

```
def three(board):

    for row in range(0, 9, 3):
        for col in range(0, 9, 3):

            b = board[row][col] + board[row][col+1] + board[row][col+2] + board[row+1][col] + board[row+1][col+1] + board[row+1][col+2] + board[row+2][col] + board[row+2][col+1] + board[row+2][col+2]
            print(b)
            # test if valid...
```

this yielded me this result:

```
435682197
269571834
781493562
826374951
195682743
347915628
519248763
326957418
874136259
```

^ this is every 3x3 within the board.

Comment: You just go trough row 1-3 and column 1-3. You have to do every combination of 1-3, 4-6 and 7-9. For both rows and columns.

Comment: Think about what indices each square in a 3x3 box has, and what the difference is between similar squares when you move to another 3x3 box.

Comment: @ph140 I do understand that, and it seems simple in words, but I can not convert that into code, I feel like it must be very easy and I am totally blanking out on this simple problem.

Comment: You are very close to getting it, Nelfael has a great tip

Comment: @Nelfeal Thanks for your tips, I will continue to think on this though so far I can only find the brute force method which I added as en edit. I know it is very brutal

Comment: What is `i` in your code?

Comment: Not an expert here, but I have a suspicion that finding which board has a solution is as hard as finding one. I would start with a solved puzzle and work backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Each 3x3 box consists of three sub-lists. For instance, the top-left box consists of these three sub-lists:

```
board[0][0:3]
board[1][0:3]
board[2][0:3]
```

The one in the center looks like this:

```
board[3][3:6]
board[4][3:6]
board[5][3:6]
```

To visit all 9 boards you can thus loop all columns that are multiples of 3, and all rows that are multiples of 3. Here each box is just the concatenation of those three sub-lists:

```
for row in range(0, 9, 3):
    for column in range(0, 9, 3):
        box = (board[row][column:column+3]
             + board[row+1][column:column+3]
             + board[row+2][column:column+3])
        # do something with box
```

As you already have a solution for a `row`, that solution can also serve for this "flattened" box -- which also has 9 elements.

To avoid code repetition, it is better to put the row-verification logic in a little function. Then you can call that function for each row, for each column and for each "flattened" box.

The counting you do with `s` works fine, but consider that as soon as you find an invalid section in your board, it is of no use to continue checking others. In that case you can just break out and immediately return out of the function, indicating it is not a valid board. If such an exit never happens and execution reaches the end of the function, you don't need to check a counter any more. The mere fact you didn't exit earlier means that the board is valid. So drop that counter.

Your function should better not print the outcome, but just *return* a boolean indicating whether the board is valid or not. Leave it to the caller what to do with that information.

Let's see what the function looks like at this point:

```
def valid(board):
    def is_complete(line):
        return line.count('1') == 1 and line.count('2') == 1 and line.count('3') == 1 and line.count('4') == 1 and line.count('5') == 1 and line.count('6') == 1 and line.count('7') == 1 and line.count('8') == 1 and line.count('9') == 1
    
    for row in board:
        if not is_complete(row):
            return False

    for column in range(9):
        line = [row[column] for row in board]
        if not is_complete(line):
            return False

    for row in range(0, 9, 3):
        for column in range(0, 9, 3):
            line = (board[row][column:column+3]
                  + board[row+1][column:column+3]
                  + board[row+2][column:column+3])
            if not is_complete(line):
                return False
    return True
```

So `is_complete` is that little function that performs the verification logic for one section of 9 cells. It just returns the boolean expression, which evaluates to True of False.

The above works fine. Now it is time look at the verification logic in the `is_complete` function. Calling `count` nine times is not efficient. It is more efficient to collect all values into a single set and verify that this set has 9 values.

Secondly, the loops that have `return False` exit points can be written using the `all` or `any` function

This leads to the following improvement:

```
def valid(board):
    def is_complete(line):
        return len(set(line)) == 9
    
    if not all(is_complete(row) for row in board):
        return False

    if not all(is_complete([row[column] for row in board]) for column in range(9)):
        return False

    if not all(is_complete(board[row][column:column+3]
                          + board[row+1][column:column+3]
                          + board[row+2][column:column+3])
                for row in range(0, 9, 3)
                for column in range(0, 9, 3)):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you! this answer was the easiest for me to understand, I was able to write this function after just reading your response once, which uses similar logic. I added the function as an edit. could you check it and give your thoughts?

Comment: You should not edit your question with an answer to your question. If you really want to post an alternative answer to your own question, then post it in the answer section, and attribute the insights you have used (like `range(0, 9, 3)`) to where you got them from. There are indeed a multitude of ways to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

In your "brute force" method, you have, in order:
`for r in range(0,3)` 3 times,
`for r in range(3,6)` 3 times,
`for r in range(6,9)` 3 times.
See a pattern? You can introduce another variable that increases by 3 each time (or increases by 1, but you multiply it by 3 before using it).

Then, inside each of these loops, you have the exact same situation but with `c` instead of `r`. You can introduce yet another variable for that. And when I say "introduce another variable", it's really more like "write an additional loop with its own index variable.

Note that you can write a for loop like this:

```
for i in [0, 3, 6]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are always good to use when reapeating things. You already have already understood the main idea, so i just made a function you can run every combination through.

```
def testbox(row, column):
    for r in range(row, row+3):
        print()
        for c in range(column, column+3):
            print(example[r][c], sep=' ', end='')
    print('\n')


for r in [0, 3, 6]:
    for c in [0, 3, 6]:
        testbox(r, c)
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, though I am kind of still struggling to understand this. Is there any way to write it without being its own function, and just using 2 for loops? There is zero chance I would have come up with this. I have been breaking my brain for 30 minutes on this.

Comment: I don't think its possible using just two loops, without also using more complex methods than functions

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain whether this is the best approach, but I managed to do it like this:

```
def validate_part(part_list):
    if type(part_list[0]) != int:
        part_list = [int(part) for part in part_list]
    num_list = list(range(1, 10))
    filled = True
    for num in num_list:
        if num not in part_list:
            filled = False
    return filled


def valid(board):
    col_list = [[] for col in range(1,10)]
    square_list = []
    check_list = {"row":[], "col":[], "square":[]}

    for idx,row in enumerate(board):
        for num in range(len(row)):
            col_list[idx].append(row[num])
        check_list["row"].append(validate_part(row))

    for col in col_list:
        check_list["col"].append(validate_part(col))

    for i in range(0,len(board),3):
        part = board[i:i+3]
        squares = [[] for s in range(3)]
        for row in range(len(part)):
            iter = 0
            for col in range(0,len(part[row]),3):
                squares[iter] += part[row][col:col+3]
                iter += 1

        square_list += squares
        
    for square in square_list:
        check_list["square"].append(validate_part(square))
        
    if False not in check_list["row"] and False not in check_list["col"] and False not in check_list["square"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```