# I wanted to make a sudoku an check if it is a valid one

Tags: python, sudoku

Does any body have an idea why my valid, or doubles methods don't want to work?
First I make a new 9x9 sudoku with al positions None. afterwards with the method doubles i check whether there are any duplicates in a row, if so I return True. A last if check  with the method valid if the row and columns are valid, if so I return true. The print_sudoku method is just to print out the sudoku nicely.

```
def make_sudoku():
   sudoku = []
   row = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
   for i in range(9):
       sudoku.append(row)
   return sudoku


def doubles(row):
    for e in range(len(row)):
        if row[e] in row:
            return True
    return False


def valid(sudoku):
    for i in range(9):
        column = []
        for j in range(9):
            column.append(sudoku[j][i])
        row = sudoku[i]
        if (doubles(row) and doubles(column)):
            return False

   # TODO in: Check Code every 9 blocks on duplicates

   return True




def print_sudoku(s):
    """
        Help functie om een sudoku mooi uit te printen
    """
    print("+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+")
    for x in range(9):
        print("|", end="")
        for y in range(9):
            if s[x][y] is not None:
                print(" ", s[x][y], " ", end="")
            else:
                print("  _  ", end="")
            if ((y+1)%3) != 0:
                print(" ", end="")
            else:
                print("|", end="")
        print()
        if ((x+1)%3 == 0):
            print("+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+")
        else:
            print("|                 |                 |                 |")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Begin debugging
    s1 = make_sudoku()
    print_sudoku(s1)

    s1[0][0] = 5
    s1[1][2] = 3
    s1[7][7] = 2
    s1[8][8] = 4

    print_sudoku(s1)

    print(valid(s1))
    s1[0][1] = 5
    print(valid(s1))
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |  _     _     _  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
|                 |                 |                 |
|  5     _     3  |  _     _     _  |  _     2     4  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
False
False
```

My wish to output would be:

```
The first sudoku + the second sudoku but than a valid one
True
False
```

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: It sounds like you have two functions which don't work - please narrow your question down to just one problem, and make sure that the code in your question is a [mcve] for that problem (i.e. the smallest amount of code which demonstrates the issue you're having). This will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Your `doubles` function will always return `True`.  It starts with `e` equal to `0`.  It then checks to see if `row[0]` is in `row`.  Of course it is.  It's present at `row[0]`.  So you've created a function to return `True`.  It's easy to fix, but even if you do, you'd only be checking for duplicates in rows and columns.  You forgot to check for duplicates in the nine 3x3 sub-squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues in the code you have written:

- `make_sudoku` only creates one row, and adds that *same* row 9 times to `sudoku`. That means you have 9 references to the *same* row. That's not what you want. You want 9 separate rows. So in each iteration of the loop a new row must be created. You can for instance *slice* the "template" row that was created before the loop.
- `doubles` always returns `True`. This is because the value at index `e` will *of course* be found in `row` -- you just retrieved it from there! Secondly, `None` is allowed to appear more than once in the same row, so that value should be ignored when making a duplicate check. What you can do is keep track for all digits (1..9) whether you have already encountered it before or not. Each time you retrieve a digit from `row` check whether you have already encountered it. If not, mark it as such.
- In `valid` you should not check that there is a duplicate in a row **and** there is a duplicate in a **column** (at the same time), but that *either* condition is true. So that `and` should be an `or`. It is boolean logic.

Here is your code with those three corrections (marked with a comment):

```
def make_sudoku():
   sudoku = []
   row = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
   for i in range(9):
       sudoku.append(row[:])  # Create a new row each time!
   return sudoku


def doubles(row):  # Completely rewritten
    collected = [False] * 10
    for val in row:
        if val is not None:  # `None` is never a problem!
            if collected[val]:  # If this digit already occurred before...
                return True
            collected[val] = True  # Mark this digit as having occurred once
    return False


def valid(sudoku):
    for i in range(9):
        column = []
        for j in range(9):
            column.append(sudoku[j][i])
        row = sudoku[i]
        if doubles(row) or doubles(column):  # One True is enough to have a problem
            return False
```

Comment: Thank you so much do you have any idea how I could check if it is valid for each 3x3 block?

Comment: Maybe take inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74074469/5459839).

Comment: I got it thank you! I was to soon asking this question, now i'am trying to make a function to solve the sudoku for me, hahahah difficult.